# How can I change the numbers/texts positions in the Update?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This script position text/numbers in front/above objects depending on the flags settings to true or false.
It was working fine when I called the method ChangeTextPosition only in the Start
but now I want to make that the changes will be also in the Update if I enable false the above or front it will remove the numbers/text and if both enabled true then it will position the numbers above and the text in front if only numbers is true it will position only the numbers above without the text at all and if only text then without the numbers.

Same it should be in the Start, if when starting the game and only one of the flags is true then only show the one is true and if both then show both.

Now when I called it in the Update it's just keep creating none stop numbers and texts.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Generatenumbers : MonoBehaviour
{
    public UnityEngine.GameObject[] objectsToNumber;
    public UnityEngine.GameObject text;
    public float yPadding;
    public bool rotateNumbers = false;
    public float rotationSpeed = 10f;
    public bool textAbove = false;
    public bool textInFront = false;
    public bool textOnFaces = false;

    private List<GameObject> newTexts = new List<GameObject>();
    private MeshRenderer[] renderer;
    private Vector3 newPos;
    private TextMesh textmesh;
    private int numbers;

    private void Start()
    {
        renderer = new MeshRenderer[objectsToNumber.Length];

        ChangeTextPosition();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (rotateNumbers == true)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < newTexts.Count; i++)
            {
                newTexts[i].transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, 10 * rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            }
        }

        ChangeTextPosition();
    }

    private void ChangeTextPosition()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < objectsToNumber.Length; i++)
        {
            GameObject newText = Instantiate(text);
            renderer[i] = newText.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();

            if (textAbove == true)
            {
                newPos = new Vector3
                (
                 objectsToNumber[i].transform.position.x,
                 ((objectsToNumber[i].transform.position.y + renderer[i].bounds.extents.y) + yPadding),
                   objectsToNumber[i].transform.position.z
                 );
            }

            if (textInFront == true)
            {
                newPos = new Vector3
                (
                 ((objectsToNumber[i].transform.position.x + renderer[i].bounds.extents.x) + yPadding),
                 objectsToNumber[i].transform.position.y,
                   objectsToNumber[i].transform.position.z
                 );
            }

            newText.transform.position = newPos;
            newText.transform.parent = transform;
            newText.name = i.ToString();
            newText.tag = "Number";
            newTexts.Add(newText);
            textmesh = newText.GetComponent<TextMesh>();
            textmesh.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, -90, 0);

            if (textAbove == true)
            {
                textmesh.text = i.ToString();
            }
            
            if (textInFront == true)
            {
                textmesh.text = "Hello World";
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

What I tried so far :

First I tried to use only the Start. The rules should be if one of the flags textAbove or textInfront is true put the numbers/text above or in front. If both are true put both text and numbers the numbers above the text in front. if both false don't add anything if one is false one is true add only the one that true.

Same rules for the Update.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Generatenumbers : MonoBehaviour
{
    public UnityEngine.GameObject[] objectsToNumber;
    public UnityEngine.GameObject text;
    public float yPadding;
    public bool rotateNumbers = false;
    public float rotationSpeed = 10f;
    public bool textAbove = false;
    public bool textInFront = false;
    public bool textOnFaces = false;

    private List<GameObject> newTexts = new List<GameObject>();
    private MeshRenderer[] renderer;
    private Vector3 newPosAbove;
    private Vector3 newPosFront;
    private List<Vector3> newPositions = new List<Vector3>();
    private TextMesh textmesh;
    private int numbers;
    private List<GameObject> textInstances = new List<GameObject>();

    private void Start()
    {
        renderer = new MeshRenderer[objectsToNumber.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < objectsToNumber.Length; i++)
        {
            textInstances.Add(Instantiate(text));
        }
        ChangeTextPosition();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (rotateNumbers == true)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < newTexts.Count; i++)
            {
                newTexts[i].transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, 10 * rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            }
        }

        //ChangeTextPosition();
    }

    private void ChangeTextPosition()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < objectsToNumber.Length; i++)
        {
            renderer[i] = textInstances[i].GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();

            if (textAbove == true)
            {
                newPosAbove = new Vector3
                (
                 objectsToNumber[i].transform.position.x,
                 ((objectsToNumber[i].transform.position.y + renderer[i].bounds.extents.y) + yPadding),
                   objectsToNumber[i].transform.position.z
                 );

                newPositions.Add(newPosAbove);
            }

            if (textInFront == true)
            {
                newPosFront = new Vector3
                (
                 ((objectsToNumber[i].transform.position.x + renderer[i].bounds.extents.x) + yPadding),
                 objectsToNumber[i].transform.position.y,
                   objectsToNumber[i].transform.position.z
                 );

                newPositions.Add(newPosFront);
            }

            for(int x = 0; x < newPositions.Count; x++)
            {
                textInstances[i].transform.position = newPositions[x];
                textInstances[i].transform.parent = transform;
                textInstances[i].name = i.ToString();
                textInstances[i].tag = "Number";
                newTexts.Add(textInstances[i]);
                textmesh = textInstances[i].GetComponent<TextMesh>();
                textmesh.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, -90, 0);

                if (textAbove == true)
                {
                    textmesh.text = i.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this is not working good even only for the Start()
It's showing only numbers and only the numbers 1,3,5 and it should show 6 numbers since there are 6 objects 3 numbers above and 3 in front. Each object should have a number above and in front.

Comment: The ChangeTextPosition() calls Instantiate() which every time will create a new instance of text. What you want to do is have a private variable called textInstance which you set inside start() using instantiate. Then inside the ChangeTextPosition dont call instantiate and instead replace newText reference with textInstance.

Comment: @leoQuint I tried but I didn't success yet to make it work only with the Start() I updated my question with what I tried.